# How can I improve my 20m transceiver microphone amplifier?

Tags: rf, microphone, oscillation, transceiver

After weeks (on and off admittedly) of debugging, I finally figured out why my homebrew 20m transceiver was oscillating on transmit.

Despite all attempts to improve grounding (I have a single copper ground plane connecting all grounds with the shortest possible leads) and keeping power leads short, it seems that some of the output signal is finding its way into the regulated 12V supply for other system modules.  One of those modules is the microphone amp.  Now I have to say, it was the very last module I suspected of causing my issues, but it all makes sense now in retrospect.

What's happening is that a tiny part of the output signal is impressed on the 12V supply (shown below as 12V) and this is modulating the Vcc node, which in-turn is modulating the biased non-inverting op-amp pin.  This then travels through the IF strip and all the amplification stages and into the final amp.  Before my mitigation efforts the output was squealing like a hog.  Now, it's better, but I get a several kHz ripple on my two-tone generated SSB output signal that is causing the output fets to get quite hot.

I've included some of the additional decoupling I made local to the mic amp in the diagram below and as I said it has improved things, but the problem isn't solved completely.  My questions are, is this circuit flawed in the respect that it's sensitive to supply fluctuations?  Should I consider a different amp circuit for my dynamic mic? Are there other mitigation techniques I could use to stabilize the circuit I have?  I honestly think I've done as much as I can down-stream towards the power amp chain to keep the output signal out of the supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxMPwJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add a bypass capacitor ("cap") across R2. Industry standard is 0.1uF.
I assume you meant to have the bias voltage as mid-supply, 6V? Skip that R7 and caps, take R1 directly to +12V and bypass R2. Voila, a solid bias supply.
R1 and R2 form a bias voltage with 6K resistance. Virtually every bias supply is bypassed.
BTW, the IC needs a 0.1uF bypass right at its pins too. Always bypass all IC supplies.

Comment: @user2320401 all great info, thanks.  I'll try that later on.  By the way, on the board the power pin of the op amp was bypassed with a 100uF and 100nF pretty much right at the pin.  That same node fed the bias network.  The 10 ohm resistor is just an old decoupling trick to create a lpf (with the decoupling caps) for noise.  Can you expand on why the bias should be fed directly from 12V, not getting that part?? Bypassing R2 I totally get, in fact I'm kicking myself I didn't remember that!